# Hazelcast IAtomicReference object synchronization

Tags: hazelcast, network-traffic

I am new to **Hazelcast**, and now I try to use `IAtomicReference<MyType>` to keep a huge Java Object at Server cluster. And alter functions are used to property CURD.

but I found when I use  `IAtomicReference.setAsync()` at client side to save it, I found the network traffic is very slow(about 0.1 KB/S).

so is there anyway we can speed up this network traffic?

Thanks

Comment: when i ping server IP, the latency is about 72ms.

Comment: What's the size of the object and network bandwidth?

Comment: @sertug the object is a tree, I tested with 2G and 40M respectively, but the results are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Hazelcast within a LAN? Otherwise you might have stability issues under a very slow or unstable network.

Hazelcast can not change the underlying network bandwidth since it's about hardware infrastructure. If your network speed is 0.1 KB/S there's nothing much you can do with it except addressing & improving network problem first.  I will try to address "how to utilize the network better" given that you have an acceptable network:

In order to utilize the network better you need to avoid/minimize remote calls in your cluster by using features like [data affinity](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#data-affinity) or [near cache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache).

Is there a specific neeed to use IAtomicReference? All hazelcast data structures are concurrent by design. Also storing a huge single object in any distributed system (including Hazelcast) is considered non-optimal, since it will bloat the network and is hard to move around. It's better if you can break it down into smaller objects and distribute over the cluster. For most caching use cases, Hazelcast IMap is sufficient.

I'd suggest looking into reference manuals and materials about Hazelcast such as: https://hazelcast.org/getting-started-with-hazelcast/ and https://hazelcast.com/resources/mastering-hazelcast/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sertug. I have found work around for this problem, that is not to send data via network, IFunction is better choice. by the way, I am using the self-defined tree in hazelcast, are you suggesting me to switch to MultiTable or IMap?

Comment: I don't know the exact use case here but if possible I'd try to avoid having a huge object at all and break it into smaller objects which can be distributed equally to the cluster by an IMap. Otherwise your approach is OK too (sending functions to data).